# Selectively synchronize files to multiple servers

Tags: rsync, aix

I'm administering a medium sized AIX landscape. We have, probably... 40 systems. We are currently using AIX 6.1 which has a command called cfmupdatenode. What this program does is lets you define a root (/cfmroot) which becomes your synchronization root. When you run cfmupdatenode -a (or -n [nodeName]) it will synchronize those files out to the appropriate servers. The way it knows is this:

The nodes are pre-defined beforehand (flux = flux.domain.com; spin = spin.domain.com; jump = jump.domain.com;etc)

Groups are also pre-defined if required (group1 = [flux, spin])

Each file under /cfmroot can have a suffix to the filename which defines where the file should go. An example is like this:

/cfmroot/etc/hosts [This file will be distributed to all defined nodes]

/cfmroot/etc/hosts.jump [This file will only be distributed to jump]

/cfmroot/etc/hosts.group1 [This file will be distributed to the nodes in group1, which is flux and spin]

It works fairly well, it's a tad bit slow, but considering everything that it does, it works well.

The problem is that we want to upgrade to AIX 7.1 which doesn't support cfmupdatenode anymore. I've searched the internet for a replacement, but I can't seem to find anything. I'm thinking that I may have to write my own, but I would prefer to use a tool that already exists.

Has anyone heard of anything similar to this out there in the wild? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check the Redbooks : http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247910.pdf

Pages 192-194, looks like you can do xCAT, or IBM Director plus Distributed Systems 
Management.

Or the generically Unix-y config management tools that John listed above.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem that cfengine or puppet or similar tools could handle quite easily.